# zend framework controller stopped working

Tags: php, zend-framework

```
class AboutController extends Zend_Controller_Action
{

    public function init()
    {
        /* Initialize action controller here */
    }

    public function indexAction()
    {
      $this->getResponse()
            ->appendBody(' hello from aboutAction');

        $this->_forward( 'nothing','index', null, array( 'email' => 'me@example' ) );  
    }

    public function contactAction()
    {
      $this->view->pageTitle="boolbool";
    }


}
```

This index action calls nothing controller's index function:

```
class NothingController extends Zend_Controller_Action

{


 public function init()

{

  /* Initialize action controller here */

  }



 public function indexAction()

  {

     $email=$this->_getParam('email','not found');
     $this->getResponse->appendBody('The email is: '.$email ); 
 }




}
```

But the nothings index action never gets triggered..I get page not found in the about page instead..why?

I cant even access my nothing controller, even when it exist in a file along with about (I can trigger the about action , though)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think your for `$this->_forward()` params are the wrong way round:

from Zend Framework's `Zend_Controller_Action` class:

```
/**
     * Forward to another controller/action.
     *
     * It is important to supply the unformatted names, i.e. "article"
     * rather than "ArticleController".  The dispatcher will do the
     * appropriate formatting when the request is received.
     *
     * If only an action name is provided, forwards to that action in this
     * controller.
     *
     * If an action and controller are specified, forwards to that action and
     * controller in this module.
     *
     * Specifying an action, controller, and module is the most specific way to
     * forward.
     *
     * A fourth argument, $params, will be used to set the request parameters.
     * If either the controller or module are unnecessary for forwarding,
     * simply pass null values for them before specifying the parameters.
     *
     * @param string $action
     * @param string $controller
     * @param string $module
     * @param array $params
     * @return void
     */
    final protected function _forward($action, $controller = null, $module = null, array $params = null)
    {
```

So for you it should be:

```
this->_forward('index', 'nothing', null, array( 'email' => 'me@example' ))
```

Comment: The problem is here ..in the two functions inside controller index:     $email=$this->_getParam('email','not found');
    $this->getResponse->appendBody('The email is: '.$email );

Comment: @DmitryMakovetskiyd That may also be the case but your '_forward()' arguments are still wrong, which is why your page doesn't get called!